# Upload issue in Django

Tags: python, django, image

Please can someone help with an issue i'm having in Django?

I've created a recipe app for a course project and want the user to upload images. I've set the model up and when I upload an image from the django admin page it works perfectly, however when I try and upload an image from the user interface, it doesn't work and it should be using the same model. The other CharField, TextField and IntergerField all work but not the ImageField and I don't know why. There is also a default no_picture.jpg however it doesn't use that either.

when the Img works the url shows as

[image: working url]

and when it doesn't the /recipes/ is missing from the URL

[image: non working url]

However I don't think there is an issue with my urlpatterns as the other data works its just the image.

Here is the models.py

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 120)    
    cooking_time = models.IntegerField(help_text = 'in mintues', default = 0 )    
    ingredients = models.CharField(max_length = 300)    
    description = models.TextField()
    pictures = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'recipes', default = 'no_picture.jpg')
```

forms.py

```
class CreateRecipeForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    cooking_time = forms.IntegerField(help_text='in minutes', required=False)
    ingredients = forms.CharField(max_length=300, required=False)
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=500, required=False)
    pictures = forms.ImageField(required=False)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def create_view(request):
    create_form = CreateRecipeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES)
    name = None
    cooking_time = None
    ingredients = None
    description = None
    pictures = None

    if request.method == 'POST':

        try:
            recipe = Recipe.objects.create(
                name = request.POST.get('name'),
                cooking_time = request.POST.get('cooking_time'),
                ingredients = request.POST.get('ingredients'),
                description = request.POST.get('description'),
                pictures = request.POST.get('pictures')
            )

            recipe.save()

        except:
            print('Error!!!')

    context = {
        'create_form': create_form,
        'name': name,
        'cooking_time': cooking_time,
        'ingredients': ingredients,
        'description': description,
        'pictures': pictures,
    }

    return render(request, 'recipes/create.html', context)
```

or if its easier here is the link the the GitHub repository

https://github.com/Jonathlon/django-app/tree/main/src

Thanks

Comment: Any reason to not use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)? Then you just have to save, and possibly validate.

Answer (score 1):

Here I can see you are created Django form so, you can get from fields data using **`form.cleaned_data['field_name']`** instead of **`request.POST.get('field_name')`** try below approach.

```py
@login_required
def create_view(request):
    create_form = CreateRecipeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if create_form.is_valid():
            name = create_form.cleaned_data['name']
            cooking_time = create_form.cleaned_data['cooking_time']
            ingredients = create_form.cleaned_data['ingredients']
            description = create_form.cleaned_data['description']
            pictures = create_form.cleaned_data['pictures']
            
            # Create Recipe object with image field assigned to the file object
            recipe = Recipe.objects.create(
                name=name,
                cooking_time=cooking_time,
                ingredients=ingredients,
                description=description,
                pictures=pictures
            )
            return render(request, 'recipes/success.html')  # Redirect to success page or any other page
        else:
            print('Form is not valid')

    context = {'create_form': create_form}
    return render(request, 'recipes/create.html', context)
```